# How to send login credentials to Mikrotik from android application

Tags: android, centos, freeradius, mikrotik

I want to send Login credentials to Mikrotik to authenticate user from android application

I have created a radius client for android application to authenticate user its working fine. but now what i want is that to send request to the mikrotik instead direct hitting the RADIUS server and then mikrotik will send data to radius server and and send response of the RADIUS server to the user.

So please tell where to find the API for this.

Comment: Can you share us the code of your redius android client? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if i understood properly your request you should enable the radius authentication in the Mikrotik device:

> PPP -> PPP Authentication & Accounting -> Check on "Use Radius"

Then hit the RADIUS button in the main menu to create a new Radius record: specify radius server IP and password (and the kind of service you want to authenticate).

I'd like to post an image but i don't have enough reputation to do that.

You won't need any API since Mikrotik will intercept and forward radius requests, sending back to your client the authentication acknowledgement.

Hope this helps

Comment: can you elaborate a Lil bit more, you can post link of that images in post

Answer (score 2):

I recently used webview component and wrote the url like this:

```
var uri = Android.Net.Uri.Parse("http://your page link/login?username=" + username + "&password=" + password);
```

Note that username and password are also variables.